# Androidの非表示画面領域について

Tags: android

Androidで常に特定領域にアプリケーションを描画することは可能でしょうか。
常にディスプレイ上部3割ほどに自作アプリケーションを描画し、下側7割ほどで他のアプリケーションを自由に使えるようにしたいと考えています。
上部3割でもタッチイベントを拾えると良いですが、必須ではないです。
そこで考えられる懸念がいくつかあります。
・完全にフルスクリーンで起動しようとするアプリから特定のディスプレイ領域を保護できるか。
・そもそも画面の特定領域を常に自作アプリケーションで占有できるか
頒布するアプリケーションではないため、Storeの基準や利用者のUX抜きで回答いただけるとありがたいです。
また、OSに手を加えることも視野に入れていますが、極力アプリケーションのみで解決できるとよいと考えています。
抽象的な質問ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

他のアプリの表示画面すべて、または一部に覆いかぶさって表示させるには、「**他のアプリの上に重ねて表示**」という特別な権限の付与と、使用する際はユーザーが明示的にこの権限を許可する必要があります。

例えばブルーライトカットのアプリや、リソースの使用状況を表示するアプリ、フローティングボタンを表示するアプリなどがこの権限を使用していると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
私の書き方が悪くてすみません。
私の質問の場合、他のアプリには一切かぶせず、ステータスバーのようなアプリが描画できない領域を作成できるかという質問です。